# saved_data tradingview saved color themes

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, tradingview-api

I am using the saved_data feature of TradingView to develop my application. I am using the following code to save the data:

```
tvWidget.value.subscribe("onAutoSaveNeeded", save);

function save () {
    tvWidget.value.save((res) => {
        SavedDataTVChart.value = {...res}
        localStorage.setItem("SavedDataTVChart", JSON.stringify({...res}));
    })
}
```

To save SavedDataTVChart to local storage and load it again on page load, I am using the following code:

```
const widgetOptions = {
        saved_data: SavedDataTVChart.value,
    };
```

The issue is that the saved_data includes the current colors theme applied to the chart, so when I change the theme, it no longer works correctly. What can I do to solve this problem? Can you please suggest a solution?

how to fix bug saved color theme in saved_data on tradingview?

Answer (score 0):

After you load the data from localStorge, set the theme back to the current theme using **changeTheme**

Example:

```
tvWidget[props.container].changeTheme('dark');
```